# Sorting file with multi threads

Tags: java, multithreading, file, sorting

I am sorting big file with by reading into chunks (Arraylist), sorting each arraylist using Collections.sort with custom comparator and writing the sorted results into files and then applying merge sort algorithm on all files.

I do it in one thread.

Will I get any performance boost if I start a new thread for every Collections.sort()?

By this I mean the following:
I read from file into List, when List is full I start a new thread where I sort this List and write to temp file.

Meanwhile I continue to read from file and start a new thread when the list is full again...

Another question that I have:

What is better for sorting:
1)Arraylist that I fill and when it's full apply collections.sort()
2)TreeMap that i fill, I don't need to sort it. (it's sorts as I insert items)

NOTE: I use JAVA 1.5

UPDATE:
This is a code I want to use, the problem are that I am reusing datalines arraylist that is beeing used by threads and also I need to wait until all threads complete. 
how do i fix?

```
int MAX_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);
List datalines = ArrayList();       
try {
   while (data != null) {
       long currentblocksize = 0;

    while ((currentblocksize <= blocksize) && (data = getNext()) != null) {
                                        datalines.add(data);
    currentblocksize += data.length();
   }                
    executor.submit(new Runnable() {                
       public void run() {
    Collections.sort(datalines,mycomparator);
    vector.add(datalines);
       }
   });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "full" when it comes to the lists? You realize that when you've sorted these sublists, you won't have sorted the whole file, right?

Comment: I mean I limit the list for lets say 1000 lines of text. after I sort the subs and write them to sub files I plan to merge-sort them.

Comment: Ah, okay - I missed that bit. How big is this file? Do you *really* need to write out the sublists to files?

Comment: yes, the file is big I can't sort in memory

Comment: I see you mentioned "lines of text". I have 3 questions: 1. Is this huge file a text file? 2. Do you open it as a text file or as a binary file? 3. What Operating System are you using?

Comment: 1)huge, 2gb+ 2)as text file 3)windows XP and windows 7

Comment: `TreeMap` will silently discard duplicates, which will cause subtle bugs regardless of performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to implement the following scheme, known as a farm:

```
             worker0
reader  -->  worker1  -->  writer
             ...
             workerN
```

Thus, one thread reads a chunk from the file, hands it to a worker thread (best practice is to have the workers as an `ExecutorService`) to sort it and then each worker sends their output to the writer thread to put in a temp file.

**Edit**: Ok, I've looked at your code. To fix the issue with the shared `datalines`, you can have a private member for each thread that stores the current `datalines` array that the thread needs to sort:

```
public class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private List datalines = new ArrayList();

    public ThreadTask(List datalines) {
        this.datalines.add(datalines);
    }

    public void run() {
       Collections.sort(datalines,mycomparator);
       synchronized(vector) {
           vector.add(datalines); 
       }
    }
}
```

You also need to synchronize access to the shared `vector` collection.

Then, to wait for all threads in the ExecutorService to finish use:

```
executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: one more thing, should I add IO file writing into the threads?

Comment: @simpleuser: Writing (or reading) to the same disk with multiple threads is never a good idea, because the disk needs to seek the next writing position and you will just keep bouncing the disk between seeks if you use multiple threads. What you should do is have another separate thread take the sorted arrays from a queue (like in the picture I put) and write them to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Whether using threads will speed things up depends on whether you're limited by disk I/O or by CPU speed. This depends how fast your disks are (SSD is much faster than spinning hard disks), and on how complex your comparison function is. If the limit is disk I/O, then there's no point in adding threads or worrying about data structures, because those won't help you read the data from disk any faster. If the limit is CPU speed, you should run a profiler first to make sure your comparison function isn't doing anything slow and silly.

Comment: I used to use Eclipse, too. But when I needed to profile I downloaded NetBeans, installed it, profiled with it, closed it, switched back to Eclipse, and never used it again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question is - yes. You will gain performance boost if you implement a parallelised version of the Merge Sort. More about this in this Dr.Dobbs article: http://drdobbs.com/parallel/229400239 .

Answer (score 0):

If your process is CPU bound (which I suspect its not) you can see an improvement using multiple threads. If your process is IO bound, you need to improve your IO bandwidth and operation speed.

Answer (score 0):

Parallelizing a sequential operation will improve performance in three cases:

1. You have a CPU-bound application, and have multiple cores that can do work without coordination. In this case, each core can do its work and you'll see linear speedup. If you don't have multiple cores, however, multi-threading will actually slow you down.
2. You have an IO-bound application, in which you're performing IO via independent channels. This is the case with an application server interacting with multiple sockets. The data on a given socket is *relatively* unimpeded by whatever's happening on other sockets. It is generally *not* the case with disk IO, unless you can ensure that your disk operations are going to separate spindles, and potentially separate controllers. You generally won't see much of a speedup here, because the application will still be spending much of its time waiting. However, it can lead to a much cleaner programming model.
3. You interleave IO and CPU. In this case one thread can be performing the CPU-intensive operation while the other thread waits on IO. The speedup, if any, depends on the balance between CPU and IO in the application; in many (most) cases, the CPU contribution is negligible compared to IO.

You describe case #3, and to determine the answer you'd need to measure your CPU versus IO. One way to do this is with a profiler: if 90% of your time is in `FileInputStream.read()`, then you're unlikely to get a speedup. However, if 50% of your time is there, and 50% is in `Arrays.sort()`, you will.

However, I saw one of your comments where you said that you're parsing the lines inside the comparator. If that's the case, and `Arrays.sort()` is taking a significant amount of time, then I'm willing to bet that you'd get more of a speed boost by parsing on read.